# What is the name of the tool that the guy in this video is using to level up the mud on ceiling?

Tags: drywall-mud, mudding

What is the name of the tool that the guy in this video is using to straighten up the ceiling?

[image]

https://youtu.be/YuUoZZ6v6MU?t=528

He is even indicating the name but I don't understand what he is saying. I am looking to buy one of those.

Comment: **ANY video like that is going to link the tools.** Why? It's a habit, this is how Youtubers get paid. Most links contain "affiliate codes" which give them a 2-3% commission if you buy the tool, or 1% of *anything else* you buy for the next 24hrs.  I once linked to a $2 electrical box, and suddenly had a $150 commission because a guy bought something huge. At 12,000 subscribers this person probably isn't quitting their day job, but paying for their hobby.

Comment: https://bartstapingtools.ca/products/columbia-tomahawk-smoothing-blades-10

Comment: expensive like hell

Comment: I mean c'mon it was in the video description.. https://www.spear-and-jackson.com/products/hand-contractor-tools/builders-tools/tyzack-plastering-tools/tyzack-plasterers-spatulas-and

Comment: yeah I now know it was there but I am not much of a youtube user so I did not know where to find the links, I was looking for them in the first comments and it was also because usually the description has a "more" button there that I never paid attention to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a link in the video for [Tyzack Plasterers Spatulas](https://www.spear-and-jackson.com/products/hand-contractor-tools/builders-tools/tyzack-plastering-tools/tyzack-plasterers-spatulas-and).  I've also heard them called "skimming blades" in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Found it using image search
https://www.amazon.ca/Quickskim-Semi-Flexible-Plastering-Rule/dp/B06ZZGSNVH

Plaster Skimming Blade